# Dead branch of _Generic expression causing compiler error (C11)

Tags: c, generics, c11

I was interested to write a type validation macro, which only gives a warning if the type isn't an int/short/long or a *pointer*.

The trouble I have with this is that a pointer can be any kind of pointer.

```
#define INT_OR_POINTER_AS_UINTPTR(v) _Generic((v), \
    signed long:  (uintptr_t)(v),            unsigned long:  (uintptr_t)(v), \
    signed int:   (uintptr_t)(v),            unsigned int:   (uintptr_t)(v), \
    signed short: (uintptr_t)(v),            unsigned short: (uintptr_t)(v), \
    default: (((void)(0 ? (*(v)) : 0),                       (uintptr_t)(v))))
```

The first block is to allow `int/short/long`

The `default` case is to allow any pointer.

The intention of `(0 ? (*(v)) : 0)` is to cause a compiler error if `v` is not a pointer, but otherwise not effect the generated code (hance the `0 ? ...`).

This way, accidental inplicit casts from other types such as `float` or `bool` won't go un-noticed.

Ideally, this would work.

```
int a = 4;
struct Foo *b = NULL;

uintptr_t test_a = INT_OR_POINTER_AS_UINTPTR(a);
uintptr_t test_b = INT_OR_POINTER_AS_UINTPTR(b);
```

Ideally, and this would fail for both uses.

```
float a = 4;
struct Foo b = {0};

uintptr_t test_a = INT_OR_POINTER_AS_UINTPTR(a);
uintptr_t test_b = INT_OR_POINTER_AS_UINTPTR(b);
```

However, even when an `int/long/short` is given as an argument, The code which checks a pointer is evaluated and errors: `invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')`

Without having to explicitly enumerate every kind of pointer type which might be passed to this `_Generic` is there a way to catch all kind of pointers, without evaluating the expression for other (non-pointer) values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incompatible pointer types passing in \_Generic macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743520/incompatible-pointer-types-passing-in-generic-macro)

Answer (score 2):

`_Bool` is a "standard unsigned integer type", see 6.2.5, so if you want special handling for that, you'll need to do it separately.

Otherwise, there's a simple trick you can use.  Integers and pointers have the property that the symmetric difference is an integer.  So we use the symmetric difference in a context that can only accept an integer, like array subscripting:

```
#define INT_OR_POINTER_AS_UINTPTR(v) \
             ((sizeof "Allow only integer and pointer types"[(v)-(v)]), (uintptr_t)(v))
```

The subtraction will fail for `struct` types, and floating-point types will yield a floating-point difference, which can't be used for pointer arithmetic.

To reject `_Bool` you can use a `_Generic`.

Comment: This has the disadvantage to evaluate `v` three times, which is a "no no!" for macros. You could pack the first part into a `sizeof` to avoid this.

Comment: @Jens: great idea (the original macro also multiply evaluated its argument)