# Explain `_Generic` error message: error: invalid type argument of unary '`*`' (have '`int`')

Tags: c, generics, gcc, clang, c11

I don't usually require assistance understanding error messages, however this one seems like it must be a bug. I've combed through the "questions that may already have your answer", but none of those appear to be using the recent `_Generic` feature added by C11, so I think this might be a unique issue. Here is my testcase:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define foo(bar) _Generic((bar), int:   sizeof (bar)   \
                               , int *: sizeof *(bar))

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", foo(42));
}
```

The error message I'm seeing for gcc 5.2 reads:

> error: invalid type argument of unary '`*`' (have '`int`')
>
> note: in expansion of macro '`foo`'

clang emits a message of similar meaning:

> fatal error: indirection requires pointer operand ('`int`' invalid)
>
> note: expanded from macro '`foo`'

These messages seem to imply one of the following:

- The compiler chose the expression from the `int *` generic association.
- The expressions from the generic associations were both evaluated.

[C11§6.5.1.1p3](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.5.1.1p3) seems to forbid both of these explanations explicitly:

> The controlling expression of a generic selection is not evaluated. If a generic selection has a generic association with a type name that is compatible with the type of the controlling expression, then the result expression of the generic selection is the expression in that generic association. Otherwise, the result expression of the generic selection is the expression in the default generic association. None of the expressions from any other generic association of the generic selection is evaluated.

Can anybody shed some light on this error message for me?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the term “evaluated”. Just because something isn't evaluated doesn't mean it can be invalid C code (`sizeof *(42)`).

Comment: @cremno: `sizeof *(42)` is perfectly valid...

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks. I missed that when reformatting the code (the `_Generic` was previously all one line). I've "fixed" the code in the question, but the error will persist nonetheless.

Comment: Looks like [this bug report](https://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-bugs@gcc.gnu.org/msg442191.html). Hasn't been accepted with the justification that type checking is not the same as evaluation.

Comment: I've always thought that `_Generic` was a terrible idea. C is **not** designed for such things as Generic Programming. Go with C++ templates if you want so.

Comment: @KemyLand _sizeof *(42) is perfectly valid_ see [this](http://ideone.com/IH6Zmn)

Comment: Note that you can add some casts to fix this.

Comment: @R.. Casts don't always work in this situation. [Modified example on Godbolt](https://goo.gl/L5cNiE)

Comment: @Seb Here's [one possible explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24746034/539810). The idea presented by that explanation is that every expression must be valid for every type that is handled. Given that `_Generic` requires an expression of a specific type to select the type, it's reasonable to assume that it was intended for expressions like `#define cbrt(x) _Generic((x), float: cbrtf, default: cbrt, long double: cbrtl)(x)`. That's an example from the C11 draft N1570 that calls the appropriate cube-root function.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: Your example compiles just fine. There's a spurious warning but that's a compiler bug; the compiler has no obligation to spam warnings for things in untaken `_Generic` choices assuming they are valid C (not constraint violations).

Comment: @R.. True. I'm used to treating warnings as indications of possible errors in my implementation of an algorithm or understanding of a C concept. `_Generic` seems to make this a very difficult habit to break. It would be nice if compilers could somehow avoid warning about this sort of thing... For now, I guess it's something that people just need to live with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is right: `sizeof *(42)` is a constraint violation because it applies the `*` to an expression of integer type. Now one thing for `_Generic` is important to know, this is not processed a preprocessing time but as a proper expression in the sense of the C language (with the highest precedence). The effects of this `_Generic` expression actually the same as doing something like

```
(1 ? sizeof (42) : sizeof *(42))
```

Here you know that the second branch is never evaluated, still nobody expects this to compile.