# _Generic to fill some union

Tags: c, c11

I want to use the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) `_Generic` keyword to fill an union according to the static type, like:

```
typedef union {
    double d;
    long l;
    const char*s;
    void*p;
} ty;

#define make_ty(X) _Generic((X),                        \
                            double: (ty){.d=(X)},       \
                            long: (ty){.l=(X)},         \
                            const char*: (ty){.s=(X)},  \
                            default: (ty){.p=(X)})

ty from_double(double x) { return make_ty(x); }
ty from_string(const char*s) { return make_ty(s); }
ty from_long(long l) { return make_ty(l);}
```

but this does not compile, e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 5.3 gives (with `gcc -std=c11 -Wall`):

```
u.c: In function ‘from_double’:
u.c:11:35: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘const char *’ 
                  using type ‘double’
              const char*: (ty){.s=(X)}, \
                                   ^
u.c:14:41: note: in expansion of macro ‘make_ty’
       ty from_double(double x) { return make_ty(x); }
```

BTW, using `gcc -std=c99 -Wall` gives the same error...

Or is `_Generic` only useful for `tgmath.h` ?

I thought that `_Generic` chooses the expression according to the compiler-known type, so the non-sensical `(ty){.s=(x)}`  would be ignored in `from_double`....

<sup>(if that did work, I would be able to "overload" `make_ty`  according the static, compiler-known, type of the argument...)</sup>

Comment: Ok, but even in `-std=c11` this does not work

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743520/incompatible-pointer-types-passing-in-generic-macro) has a similar problem and the top answer probably answers your question

Comment: Other answers on the same topic seem to suggest that the other cases are not allowed to contain a *constraint violation*  (wrong type for initializer is indeed one of those)

Comment: As a side note, with those function declarations you have already restricted the type, so there's no need for _Generic here. `ty from_double(double x) { return (ty){.d=x}; }` and so on does the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All branches of `_Generic` must be valid code, just as much as in something like `if (1) { here; } else { there; }`. To have a solution you could take it the other way around. Define functions similar to:

```
inline ty from_double(double x) { return (ty){ .d = x }; }
```

for all your cases and then have the macro as:

```
#define make_ty(X) _Generic((X),                     \
                            double: from_double,     \
                            double: from_long,       \
                            ...)(X)
```

With the visibility through `inline` compilers are actually able to optimize such code and will usually not pass through calling the function pointer.