# How do I choose between a function with floating point argument vs pointer to float at compile time in C11

Tags: c, pointers

Lets say I have the following code that initially deals with  ints:

```
#define F_INT(x) _Generic((x), int: f_int(x), int *: f_intptr(x))

void f_int(int x) {printf("int\n");}
void f_intptr(int *x) {printf("intptr\n");}

int main() 
{
    int x;
    F_INT(x);
}
```

The above code will display "int" because  `x` is declared as an `int`. If `x` is declared as pointer to `int`,  the above code will display  "intptr". So far so good, even though the code produces warnings.

However if I switch everything to floats, then I get errors. If I declare `x` as `float`, I get:

> error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘f_floatptr’
>   ...
>   note: expected ‘float *’ but argument is of type ‘float’

If  I declare `x` as `float *`,  I get the opposite error.

`_Generic` keyword seems to compile type check all selections even though the whole point should be that only one selection is chosen at compile time.

How do I get the above to work. I tried function pointers as a work around, but couldn't work around the issue.

Comment: Can you show the version that has problems?

Comment: "*So far so good, even though the code produces warnings.*" -- Don't ignore warnings. I compiled your code (after adding the required `#include <stdio.h>` and got two warnings for things a stricter compiler could have treated as fatal errors (constraint violations). Implicit pointer/floating-point conversions are no more valid than implicit pointer/integer conversions; your compiler (gcc?) just happens to be more lax about the latter. Update your question to show the warnings you get **with the code in the question**, and ask how to fix those warnings. Switching to floats is a red herring.

Comment: Only one of the generic-associations in a generic-selection has its expression evaluated, but they're all compiled. See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5.1.1.

Comment: @NetMage: Actually, he has shown us a version that has problems. He just didn't show us the warnings.

Comment: #define F_INT(x)  _Generic((x), int : f_int((int) x),  int *: f_intptr((int *) x))            fixes the warnings by doing explicit cast.  But  it does not help with the float version.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong.  The above does not eliminate the warning, just changes it to something else. Anyway the answer from nemequ below seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much a duplicate of [Incompatible pointer types passing in _Generic macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743520/incompatible-pointer-types-passing-in-generic-macro)

You can use something like this instead:

```
#define F_INT(x) _Generic((x), int: f_int, int *: f_intptr)(x)
```

Or, if you want to add floats:

```
#define F_INT(x) _Generic((x), int: f_int, int *: f_intptr, float: f_float, float *: f_floatptr)(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, the above seems to work!