# GCC: why cannot compile clean printf("%f\n", f16) under -std=c11 -Wall?

Tags: c, gcc, printf, language-lawyer, half-precision-float

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT__
#include <float.h>

#ifdef FLT16_MAX
_Float16 f16;
int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", f16);
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

Invocation:

```
# gcc trunk on linux on x86_64
$ gcc t0.c -std=c11 -Wall
```

Expected diagnostics:

```
<nothing>
```

Actual diagnostics:

```
t0.c:9:14: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type '_Float16' [-Wformat=]
    9 |     printf("%f\n", f16);
      |             ~^     ~~~
      |              |     |
      |              |     _Float16
      |              double
```

Does it mean that under `__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT__` AND if `FLT16_MAX` defined the gcc is unaware that `printf` may be used with `_Float16`? Should it be aware?

Also: `printf("%f\n", f);` when `f` is a `float` leads to no warning above despite the fact that `format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'float'`. Confused.

Comment: A `float` passed to `...` is automatically promoted to `double`. Maybe that doesn't happen for the non-standard `_Float16`?

Comment: Note that gcc does not provide the implementation of `printf`. It's implemented by the C library, which could be glibc, newlib, musl, or any of a number of others.

Comment: @KeithThompson while it's possible to override, normally a C implementation provides its own standard library, and it generates warnings based on that.

Comment: @Barmar gcc in particular is a compiler, not a complete C implementation, and it does not provide an implementation of `printf`. A typical C implementation might include gcc, glibc, binutils, and other components.

Comment: @KeithThompson Does it mean that any conforming C compiler can be used with any conforming C library?

Comment: @pmor No, the compiler and library have to be compatible. Strictly speaking, as far as the C standard is concerned, there's no such thing as a "conforming compiler" or a "conforming library"; conformance applies to the implementation as a whole. An example: In some versions of MinGW (gcc with Microsoft's library), the compiler and library disagree about the size of `long double`.  Neither is wrong, but they don't work correctly together (though there are workarounds).

Comment: @KeithThompson Re: "there's no such thing as...": exactly, thanks! Another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69976945/clang-why-stdc-iec-559-depends-on-include-stdio-h): on Linux both gcc (now seems fixed) and clang define `__STDC_IEC_559__` to `1` in `glibc-2.25/include/stdc-predef.h`, while it is expected to be defined by the compiler itself. Since clang does not define `__GCC_IEC_559`, then `__STDC_IEC_559__` is (incorrectly?) defined to `1` by `stdc-predef.h`.

Comment: @KeithThompson As a result: under `-ffp-model=fast` (behaves identically to specifying both `-ffast-math` and `ffp-contract=fast`) AND if `stdc-predef.h` is included (as a part of `#include <standard_header>`), then it is unclear, for which purpose the `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined to `1`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Re: "while it is expected to be defined by the compiler itself": Hence, the compiler shall know _in advance_ whether its library conforms to the specifications in the annex F.

Comment: Typo: before: `(incorrectly?)`, after `(unexpectedly)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [clang manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html):

> Because default argument promotion only applies to the standard floating-point types, `_Float16` values are not promoted to `double` when passed as variadic or untyped arguments. As a consequence, some caution must be taken when using certain library facilities with `_Float16`; for example, there is no `printf` format specifier for `_Float16`, and (unlike `float`) it will not be implicitly promoted to `double` when passed to `printf`, so the programmer must explicitly cast it to double before using it with an `%f` or similar specifier.

Comment: If "_Float16 values are not promoted to double ...", then does it mean that `printf("%f\n", f16);` triggers UB?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: Why "Future standardization may include additional floating-point types, including those with greater range, precision, or both than long double" (N2596) and not less range, precision, or both than float?

Comment: Who knows. I doubt that's a normative statement, it's just speculation.

Comment: They probably didn't think there would likely be any need for less precision. The direction that computers have been going for decades is bigger, not smaller.

Comment: Why the support of `long long` and floating types is mandatory for a conforming implementation targeting hardware with no support of > 32 bit integers nor support of floating-point arithmetic (no FPU)?

Comment: Please don't ask me to speculate on the decisions of the standards committee. They've probably published a Rationale, I suggest you search for it.

Comment: 1) "including those with greater range, precision, or both than long double": this does not mean "excluding those with less range, precision, or both than float". 2) Unexpected that: a) compiler does support `_Float16`, but b) does not support promotion to double in `printf`. It seems that C standard misses this (or similar) requirement: "all the supported additional floating-point types with precision less than double are required to support promotion to double when passed as variadic or untyped arguments".